# charachterAtIndex max range?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've got some text in a textfield, they start of with 6 characters and my own input is also 6 character long, I use this code to get them a part for comparison:

```
unichar aChar1 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:6];
    unichar aChar2 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:7];
    unichar aChar3 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:8];
    unichar aChar4 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:9];
    unichar aChar5 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:10];
    unichar aChar6 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:11];
```

Now when I do this it pauses my simulator but when I turn 6,7,8,9,10,11 in 0,1,2,3,4,5 Then It does work. how come?

(*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds') can someone explain it to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you have a 12-character string containing both the starting value and your input, concatenated together? I strongly suspect that that's not the case.

Using the debugger, break on the first line in your question and go `po [mainTextController text]` in the debug console. You'll find that the string isn't as long as you expect it to be.

Comment: Great you two really made me think about that, so I added a little delay so I'd make sure that my own input character where there at the time my code was trying to get them separator, and it worked! thanks I did it with: dispatch_after( dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1* NSEC_PER_SEC ),
                   dispatch_get_current_queue(),^{

Comment: I don't understand why you would need a delay. What event are you responding to?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a character that is out of the range of the text string in mainTextController.text

You should check the length of the string before accessing that character:

```
if([mainTextController.text length] > 12)
{
    unichar aChar6 = [mainTextController.text characterAtIndex:11];
}
```

Comment: Great you two really made me think about that, so I added a little delay so I'd make sure that my own input character where there at the time my code was trying to get them separator, and it worked! thanks I did it with: dispatch_after( dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1* NSEC_PER_SEC ),
                   dispatch_get_current_queue(),^{